# Rails seed circular dependecy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I updated Rails today to Rails 4.1 (from 4.0) and now my seed.rb doesnt work anymore, here is the problem:

This line

```
ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures", "marketplace_categorias")
```

Gives me this error:

```
rake aborted!
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MarketplaceCategoria
```

But on console, the same line gives me this:

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant MarketplaceCategoria, expected /home/user/Documents/wsrails/myproject/app/models/marketplace/marketplace_categoria.rb to define it
```

As you can see I have a namespaced model, defined like this

```
class Marketplace::MarketplaceCategoria < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name = 'marketplace_categorias'
....
end
```

So it seens that Rails is trying to autoload the wrong constant, it should load Marketplace::MarketplaceCategoria, instead of MarketplaceCategoria.

Just to add, I able to create records via console with no problems, and when I run on console the command:

```
Marketplace::MarketplaceCategoria.table_name
=>"marketplace_categorias"
```

Showing me the right table name.

What I'm doing wrong here ?

plus: My migration

```
class MarketplaceCategoria < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :marketplace_categorias do |t|
       t.string :nome
       t.string :slug, :unique => true 
       t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :marketplace_categorias, :slug,   :unique => true
  end
end
```

Comment: Just confirmed, this error only happens on rails 4.1.1, when I did a rollback to rails 4.0.5, works perfect

Comment: Is your model in `app/models/marketplace/marketplace_categoria.rb`?

Comment: Yes it is... This task actually works on another rails version...